# add_menu_page not working with in-class function

Tags: wordpress

I'am trying to use `add_menu_page` to create a custom "custom_post" page. (Is this a mistake already or not ? :-/)

Here's the code that won't work :

```
add_menu_page( 'projets' , 'projets' , 'edit_posts', 'ajouter_projet' , array( $this, 'afficher_admin_page' ) , $img_url, 5);
```

But when I use this

```
add_menu_page( 'projets' , 'projets' , 'edit_posts', 'ajouter_projet' , afficher_admin_page' , $img_url, 5);
```

with the function `afficher_admin_page` out of my class, it works.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Is the "custom_post" page supposed to be shown in admin or frontend? `add_menu_page` is for admin side only.

Comment: codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

"The function must be referenced in one of two ways:

    1. if the function is a member of a class within the plugin it should be referenced as array( $this, 'function_name' )
    2. in all other cases, using the function name itself is sufficient "

Make sure that the class is accessible. Check what $this actually contains. Also you have a random right ) in the working version that doesn't seem like it should be valid php syntax.

Comment: It's a backend page only (though the custom post type is to be seen by normal visitors)

Comment: The class seems accessible because my action hooks uses the class to add the menu page (which works in one way). I tried to var_dump $this, and it comes out null... This is the reason it can't be used, but I don't understand how non static methods in my class can be used by WP without creating an instance of it (but maybe this question doesn't make sense. T_T)

Answer (score -3):

Please use the link

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page
```

this will definitely helps you.